# How can I attach wooden shelf to a ShelfTrack bracket?

Tags: shelving

So, I am planning to do 3 16" shelves mounted on a ShelfTrack system side-by-side for my in-wardrobe storage area. Material for the shelves is probably going to be standard 3/4" pine or plywood (can I go thinner?). Question: what is the best way to attach shelves to the brackets? Currently I am eyeing three options:

- Using guiding inserts, like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=bI8kImf3Sms). Pros: easy assemble and disassemble. Cons: might not be that strong.
- Screwing them together from below. Pros: strong connection. Cons: minor con in height requirement.
- Trying to mount shelf on level of the bracket, similar to how [Elfa decor](https://makingprettyspaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/elfahomeworkstation-20-987x1024.jpg) does this. Pros: helps me save ~1/2" of height per shelf, looks good. Cons: much harder to make.

  - Possible way 1: cut off about half of the shelf where the bracket would be mounted, then screw bracket to what is remaining there.
  - Possible way 2: Cut off most of the wood over the bracket, leaving only a few mm for decorative purposes. Then find and/or bend another bracket to hook sideways over the ShelfTrack one and hold the shelf from below, kind of like this:
    [image: Approximate scheme for way #2, not to scale]

*Approximate scheme for way #2, not to scale*

How can I do this so it does not cost too much?

Comment: When you ask "Best way", it is inviting opinions, which would make it off topic.  I have changed it, you may revert it back if you dont agree.

Answer (score 1):

Each bracket type will prescribe its shelf attachment options. Choose the bracket type that best aligns with your design goals. If the shelves are a couple inches wider than the support spacing, then no attachment is necessary. Under "keep it simple, stupid," this would be my first choice.

Rather than choosing a plywood shelf thickness, instead choose a plywood span rating. A span rating of 32/16, for instance, indicates that the plywood requires supports on 32" centers for roof applications and supports on 16" centers for floor applications. A rating of 16/* (where "*" is a placeholder for any value) indicates a maximum deflection of 0.067" under 35 psf loading. A rating of */16 (where "*" again is a placeholder for any value) indicates a maximum deflection of 0.044" under 100 psf loading. See Table 8 from [NIST PS 1-19](https://www.nist.gov/document/doc-ps-1-19-structural-plywood).

Plywood has a [strength axis](https://www.sbcmag.info/article/2011/strength-axis-wood-structural-panels), so be sure to cut correctly oriented shelves. The wood grain in the outer plies should span from support bracket to support bracket.